# What is the procedure to file an RTI act against the police for a case on IPC507?

Tags: criminal-law, police, india, indian-penal-code

I have already filed a case on ipc507 in Hadapsar police station in Pune.

I have to check the proceedings of the case through the RTI to the Superintendent of the Police.

What is the procedure to file such a case?

Answer (score 1):

in India RTI is not applicable to police stations and courts